# Set Form.AcceptButton to none/no buttons

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

i was able to set my forms accept button with `this.AcceptButton = button1`, but how do i disable accept button so there won't be any Accept Buttons?

Comment: `this.AcceptButton = null;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `this.AcceptButton` proprerty to null.

```
this.AcceptButton = null;
```